# Norwegian character search issue in MySQL with php

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

Getting problem with Norwegian characters with upper and lower case in search with php and MYSQL-

If i pass character in capital letter it works for example character is - Ø (capital letter)

And if pass ø (small letter) it does not return any record.

But if i copy and past query in MySQL editor then it works.

I don't have any idea it's php problem or MySQL problem and how i can fix it.

---

After doing some work now i came to know maybe it's PDO issue that making difference case sensitive in characters for example - "å", "ø", "æ", "Å", "Ø", "Æ"
Still don't know how to fix.

Comment: More information please. What encoding and collation is the column? What encoding is the data coming from PHP in and what is the connection encoding? What's the data you're trying to match?

Comment: Hi deceze,
I'm using utf8_unicode_ci as column collection and utf8 as charset.
Issue is small letter is not working for example if i search for 'a' we should get result for 'A' as well. but this not happening in case  of norwegian characters.

Comment: What does this give you? 
SELECT "a"="A","å"="Å","ø"="Ø", "Æ"="æ","a"="b";

Comment: Hi Strawberry,
it works for a and A issue in "ø"="Ø", "Æ"="æ" those type of characters if i enter ø then it should return all record those having "ø" OR "Ø" but it returns only those having "ø".